# How can I make these tables responsive and have them stack up once the screen size gets smaller?

Tags: html

edited

How can I make this responsive?
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6678/

---

```
<td valign="center">Morbi vel libero ac tellus suscipit elementum a eu neque.
 Praesent mollis, orci eu malesuada accumsan, nulla magna imperdiet ipsum, in
 tempor diam nisi eget tortor. Nam id elementum quam. </td>
```

Comment: Must you use tables for layout? Bootstrap provides spectacular tools for what you're doing. Tables are for data. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Search about media querys

Comment: Back we go to 1995 then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use tables for what you're doing here. If you use divs instead you can set grid classes on them in bootstrap which will make the layout responsive (change when the screen size changes).

See here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: but there seems to be problems now.. when you slowly adjust the screen sizes, the input boxes clash

Comment: Start by setting the width to 100% instead of a set pixel value. Also you should have a div with a container class around the .row divs.

Does that help?